# Windows 7 hangs on shutdown until external drive is unplugged

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, shutdown

Occasionally (maybe 1/20 times) my pc will get stuck when shutting down until I remove one of my external hard drives. This happens regardless of whether I have accessed the drive.

What could be causing this, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Not much of a solution but try ejecting your external drive before shutting down. Probably wouldn't be the easiest to test either if it really happens .5/10 times.

Comment: How is the external drive connected?

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. Windows 7 is performing a maintenance task, e.g. optimizing the drive, checking the file system for errors, or indexing the files.
2. Data has not yet been written to the HDD due to write caching. Since some external HDD "sleep" after not being used for a few minutes, it may take another minute for the drive to spool up and write the data.
3. An application may be using the HDD, even though you have not intentionally opened any files there. The application might be using the drive for temporary files or look to that drive to store data.

Though it may be your only choice, unplugging a drive during shutdown could damage its filesystem; if possible, eject the HDD through the *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* CPL app before shutdown... this would also indicate if the drive cannot be ejected.

You can also use a tool such as [CrystalRich's *LockHunter*](http://lockhunter.com/) *before* attempting shutdown to see if something is using that drive... of course, if this happens only one time in 20, then you may have to check many times to observe the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's any application just regularly using it though, from windows itself or otherwise, as the pc will stay on the windows "shutting down..." screen for multiple days at least if I do not unplug the drive. I assume any maintenance task, read/writing or any kind of application (if it hasn't been force shut down by windows already) would be long finished at that point.

Comment: It seems you've done some useful checking; you're right that tasks should have completed (from your original post, I did not know you had waited days). One other possibility, in addition to locking (see LockHunter): the external HDD  may be having issues. Use *Xinorbis*, *Crystal Disk Info* or other utility to check the SMART status; see http://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/.